# Max sum for the continous N rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlclr

I've the following table (both `A` and `B` are integers):

**Update 1** - Could anyone do me a favour and run the solution on a set of 1M records with B being a random decimal (to avoid overflows) residing in [0 to 1] range for N=> 10, 100 and 1000? I'd like to get a flavor of the time, required to run the solution query. Thanks a lot in advance.

Sample data:

```
A   B
1   1
2   8
3   1
4   11
5   1
6   1
7   6
8   1
9   1
10  2
```

How do I get the maximum Sum of `B` values for any N sequential `A`'s? The solution mustn't use cursors, usage of table vars/tem tables has to be stongly justified.

I can use SQLCLR in case if it'll give a distinct performance boost.

Some clarifications:

- Max Sum for 1 element is 11 (see A = 4)
- Max Sum for 2 elements is 12 (it's either A=> 1 & 2 or A=> 2 & 3),
- Max Sum for 3 elements is 20 (A=>2, 3, 4),
- Max Sum for 4 is 21 (A=>1,2,3,4 or A=>2,3,4,5) etc.

Comment: What do you mean by Maximum sum of B, can you please update the question to include the expected result?

Comment: Presumably for N=3, The answer would be 8+1+11 = 24?

Comment: please see my update with sample results.

Comment: Are the `A` values guaranteed to be *consecutive* integers from `1` upwards?

Comment: @Jon Egerton 8+1+11 = 20, otherwise correct:)

Comment: So basically the [Maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) but for a fixed size of sub array?

Comment: @Martin Smith A must be sequential, also I'm looking a solutions which shines MS SQL Server 2008. I could have done it just by looping thru the values and keeping the max sum of N sequentual values, which I believe is a bad solution.

Comment: @Dmitry - You said in earlier reply to AakashM's comment that they are guaranteed sequential.

Comment: @Dmitry: Bit of brain fade there!!!

Comment: @Martin Smith Correct, I must've misread your comment - what I was trying to say is you can't just cherry pick the N highest values, values, the values have to be sequential (otherwise the Max of 3 will be 25 = 8 + 11 + 6).

Comment: @Jon Egerton - Most people experience brain fade on Friday afternoon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `A` values are guaranteed to be consecutive integers, given `N` we know for any particular `A` which values we are interested in. So

```
SELECT
    A,
    (SELECT SUM(B) FROM Table T2 WHERE T.A <= T2.A AND T2.A <= T.A + N - 1) 
        AS SumOfBs
FROM Table T
WHERE A + N - 1 <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table)
```

gives, for each `A`, the sum of the `B` values for the `N` rows starting there. The `WHERE` restricts us to rows that do actually have `N` rows starting there. Put this in a subquery and we can get the maximum:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(SumOfBs) AS DesiredValue
FROM
(
    SELECT
        A,
        (SELECT SUM(B) FROM Table T2 WHERE T.A <= T2.A AND T2.A <= T.A + N - 1) 
            AS SumOfBs
    FROM Table T
    WHERE A + N - 1 <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table)
) Intermediate
```

should do the job.

Comment: RE: Your "don't need to worry" what if some of the integers are negative?

Comment: @Martin Smith Absolutely not.

Comment: @Dmitry - Absolutely not.. what? Is `B` guaranteed positive? Didn't see that constraint mentioned in your question.

Comment: You dont need to worry bout negative values, they are guranteed to be positive.

Comment: @Martin Smith Just relax a bit, will ya?:) the word 'guaranteed' implies 'ease' rather than 'restriction'.

Answer (score 1):

I've loaded your test data into a table called `data`.

The following SQL gives me the answer `20` for N=3:

```
declare @N int
set @N = 3

select max(SumB)
from data d
cross apply (select SumB = SUM(B) from data sub where sub.A between d.A - (@N-1) and d.A) x
```

Comment: thanks, lemme try it. How performant is 'cross'? I will rarely be looking for large N's, but the size of the table can be 1M++ rows.

Comment: For large values of `N` this and Akash's answer will both suffer from similar problems as calculating running totals in that they repeatedly re-sum the same values.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Each row has to be included in N sums - yes its a 0(N) problem. Would be interested in how it could be otherwise. (Note that the scale issue wasn't stipulated in the question!)

Comment: @Jon - In Denali I think the enhanced `OVER` clause will make this trivial until then for large `N` the usual running totals techniques could probably be customised for this (quirky update, [CLR](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/running-sums-yet-again-sqlclr-saves-the-day.aspx))

Comment: How do you improve it? I don't mind using temp/helper tables as long as it'll boost the performance and won't generate large IO footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with cte as 
(select 1 window_count union all
 select window_count+1 window_count from cte where window_count<@N)
select max(sum_B) from
(select T1.A,
       sum(T2.B) sum_B
 from MyTable T1
 cross join cte
 join MyTable T2 on T1.A = T2.A + cte.window_count - 1
 group by T1.A) sq
```

Comment: thanks will do. I've not Sql here, I'll post the details once I'll try all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm possibly not understanding the question fully, but it looks to me like...

```
SELECT SUM(B) FROM table WHERE A <= n
```

If not correct, can you explain a bit more?